# Cargo MPI with Rust won't build due to error: failed to run custom build command for `libffi-sys v0.6.0`

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, mpi, rust-cargo

I am having problems getting started with Rust and MPI! I can't get Cargo to build my project. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
konst@ub0:~/rust_proj/bobo$ cargo build
   Compiling libc v0.2.66
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling memchr v2.2.1
   Compiling log v0.4.8
   Compiling glob v0.2.11
   Compiling cfg-if v0.1.10
   Compiling regex v0.2.11
   Compiling ucd-util v0.1.5
   Compiling libloading v0.4.3
   Compiling bitflags v1.2.1
   Compiling utf8-ranges v1.0.4
   Compiling unicode-width v0.1.7
   Compiling ansi_term v0.11.0
   Compiling bindgen v0.31.3
   Compiling strsim v0.8.0
   Compiling vec_map v0.8.1
   Compiling lazy_static v0.2.11
   Compiling quote v0.3.15
   Compiling peeking_take_while v0.1.2
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.17
   Compiling semver-parser v0.7.0
   Compiling make-cmd v0.1.0
   Compiling gcc v0.3.55
   Compiling custom_derive v0.1.7
   Compiling abort_on_panic v1.0.0
   Compiling thread_local v0.3.6
   Compiling regex-syntax v0.5.6
   Compiling textwrap v0.11.0
   Compiling clang-sys v0.21.2
   Compiling semver v0.9.0
   Compiling build-probe-mpi v0.1.1
   Compiling conv v0.3.3
   Compiling rustc_version v0.2.3
   Compiling log v0.3.9
   Compiling aho-corasick v0.6.10
   Compiling memchr v1.0.2
   Compiling atty v0.2.13
   Compiling which v1.0.5
   Compiling nom v3.2.1
   Compiling clap v2.33.0
   Compiling mpi v0.5.4
   Compiling cexpr v0.2.3
   Compiling env_logger v0.4.3
   Compiling libffi-sys v0.6.0
   Compiling mpi-sys v0.1.2
error: failed to run custom build command for `libffi-sys v0.6.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/konst/rust_proj/bobo/target/debug/build/libffi-sys-4c70f12629a49359/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
./autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found
thread 'main' panicked at 'Generating configure', /home/konst/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libffi-sys-0.6.0/build.rs:27:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.

warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Not considering the target directory, this is what my current project directory looks like:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    └── main.rs

1 directory, 3 files
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "bobo"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["konst"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
mpi = "0.5"
```

This is my `main.rs` file. I just wanted to get a first example of MPI in Rust running.

```
extern crate mpi;

use mpi::traits::*;

fn main() {
    let universe = mpi::initialize().unwrap();
    let world = universe.world();
    let size = world.size();
    let rank = world.rank();
    let processor = mpi::environment::processor_name().unwrap();

    println!(
        "Hello world from processor {}, rank {} out of {} processors\n",
        processor, rank, size
    );
}
```

I want to run MPI with Rust in a program. It looks like I included `mpi = "0.5"` as a dependency in the `Cargo.toml` file. For some reason, the problem is not with the mpi package, but with `libffi-sys v0.6.0`. I do not know what that is. Googling some about that revealed no interesting information about it. I'm now stuck here. Please forgive me. I am new to Rust and Cargo, and installing packages in general. Please give as many details as possible to your steps when you describe your answer.

Comment: the error message say you need to install "autoreconf"

Comment: @Stargateur How should I do that? Using `apt-get`?

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you, that worked. I used `sudo apt-get install autoconf` then `cargo clean` and `cargo build` again.